# HTML 5 audio element bug in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, audio

I've got a pretty silly bug in Chrome with the HTML5 audio element. Basically if I try to set the currentTime immediately after setting the source and then try to play, it throws an exception. This only occurs in Chrome.

**Plunker** : https://plnkr.co/edit/GZm9nZkmrt0ZvX6D85Qy?p=preview

```
<audio id="audio_0" src = "https://d2zsljmk3mm9kv.cloudfront.net/assets/samples/56c5a7c03f511270e90cb9373ea22a43d6f37082/112eeb9ddba02ec9"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#audio_0")[0].currentTime = 80;
    $("#audio_0")[0].play();
});
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations on trying to play after seekend, oncanplaythrough etc events but no luck. The only way to get it to work is to wait long enough for it to load the entire file which is just not acceptable.

Has anyone been able to get around this? Note that jPlayer does the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: The exception is only in the console right ? If so, this is because the `play()` call is being canceled by the async `seek`, and thus they do throw an error in the `play`'s returned callback. Could be seen as a bug, but really not important since everything should still work.

Comment: But it doesn't play, have you tried running the plnkr? Came across similar comments to yours when researching so I'm wondering if it's the same issue or different.

Comment: Sorry missed the plunkr. There is indeed something strange, maybe with your file, or the way it is sent from your server. Even when playing manually, it does stop at random positions... first @01:20, then setting it directly through the controls allowed to buffer more data and your script did work, until 02:16. It's like chrome looses the connection at some point. And click the play icon again makes it reload the media from the beginning. I would incriminate `Cache-Control:public, must-revalidate, max-age=0` and `Content-Disposition:inline; filename=112ee...` headers but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks. I will try a basic cdn url and see how it goes.

Comment: Be sure it sends it as `audio/mp3` and not as `inline`

Comment: Totally strange. After it throws that exception it won't start playing again.